# How to copy values from a table to another table C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql

l have a table named Students and it has StudentID which is primary key and another table is StdAccounts and it has StudentID as well.

When l register someone l want program to copy StudentID(from Students) to StudentID(StdAccounts)
l searched my problem on internet. Found something and tried to change. This is what l did and doesnt work

```
INSERT INTO (StdAccounts(StudentID), StudentPassword)
  select s.StudentID FROM Students s
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT StudentID FROM StdAccounts std
                    WHERE s.StudentID = std.StudentID) VALUES (@Password)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _doesnt work_? What error you get?

Comment: l got syntax error ( and keyword VALUES

Comment: l wonder why my question has got down vote :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put @Password in the select-list:

```
INSERT INTO StdAccounts (StudentID, StudentPassword)
  select s.StudentID, @Password FROM Students s
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT StudentID FROM StdAccounts std
                    WHERE s.StudentID = std.StudentID)
```

Comment: Yeah I also didn't get the reason for downvote. you query should do the job.

Comment: l did not downvote you. l do not have 125 reputation to vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe:

```
INSERT INTO 
    StdAccounts
    (
        StudentID
        ,StudentPassword
    ) 
select top 1 
    StudentID,
    @Password
FROM Students
WHERE 
    Password = @Password
```

although really you shouldn't be doing this in a single select statement.

I mean you can see the obvious problem which forces you to use 'top 1' is clearly not suitable for variables called 'password'

Comment: So do you suggest me to delete StdAccounts table and create a column named Password into Students ?

l was thinking that it is safe to create another table for Student ID and Password

Comment: No, I've just tried to answer your question and not judge your solution. But I don't want to get down voted by people who think I'm saying this is a good thing!

Comment: I mean if you don't have a  password col in Students and you are adding a new row to StdAccounts. what studentId do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO StdAccounts(StudentID, StudentPassword)
  select StudentID ,@Password FROM Students 
  WHERE StudentID not in (SELECT StudentID FROM  StdAccounts std
                               inner join Students s 
                               on s.StudentID = std.StudentID
                         )
```